# add blazor WASM to net core aspnet app using React SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

The project is a Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" net8.0 web app that has React v16 configured

part of startup.cs

```
...
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    // endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

 app.UseSpa(
     spa =>
     {
         spa.Options.DefaultPage = "/index.html";
         spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
         }
     });
...
```

The project is of reasonable size, we want to port it over to Blazor incrementally.

I created a Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly" project (net8.0).  All nuget updates have been applied so all versions are using 8.x.x

The goal is to have the React app still up and running by default. Then a subfolder say mysite.com/bapp to be the root for the Blazor app. As we build more of the Blazor app, the React app will route to the correct Blazor page. Eventually allowing us to remove the React app.

I can run the blazor project directly and the counter component shows and increments the number.

I have this file in `Pages/bapp` folder in the existing web app

```
@page
@using Codwellers.Prsto.Blazor.Client.Pages

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

this is the index
@{
}
<component type="typeof(Counter)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```

When I navigate to localhost:44300/ the React app starts and navigation etc works correctly

When I navigate to localhost:44300/bapp, the counter component does load, but I get a 404 on the blazor.webassembly.js

```
GET https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The webapp has a reference to the Blazor project.  The package references are

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="8.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="8.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="2.2.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="8.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="8.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="5.3.3">
```

I don't know what I am missing to at least be able to get the _framework folder to be added to the web app.

Comment: Could you pls share a minimal repo?